# Flutter: Permission denied writing file

Tags: io, flutter

I am having a problem writing a file in Flutter. I keep getting this error:

`FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/data/local/tmp/temp.png' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)`

For some reason, it's only happening on some devices. I can't seem to duplicate the problem myself, but people are reporting it to me.

Here's the basic code:

```
final Io.Directory systemTempDir = Io.Directory.systemTemp;
final Io.File file = await new Io.File('${systemTempDir.path}/temp.png').create();
file.writeAsBytes(finalImage);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be a problem with the paths depending on the device being used. Have a look at the path_provider plugin: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

There's a good write-up of how to read and write files in the Flutter Cookbook on flutter.io: https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/

Comment: That did it! Imported `path_provider` and changed `Io.Directory.systemTemp;` to `getTemporaryDirectory()` and it works! Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to access /storage/emulated/ directory but getting error "Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)" while i have granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Same here. Could you fix your problem?

Answer (score 9):

In Android Q, just add the Following Lines in AndroidManifest file:

```xml
 <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: Hey, the build fails if I add this and the minSdkVersion is below 29

Comment: Strange that this fixed my issue on android 10, even though i have targetSdkVersion 31. Does "requestLegacyExternalStorage" have any effect at all on Android 10+ devices when  targetSdkVersion 31 ?

Answer (score 4):

`final Io.Directory systemTempDir = Io.Directory.systemTemp;` seems to not work in release mode.

I had to do as below:

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final File file = File("${tempDir.path}/$fileName");
```

`getTemporaryDirectory()` is provided by path_provider.