# Flutter/Dart: Create file error - "Read-only file system"

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been struggling to create files with Flutter/dart. Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class FileManager {
  createFile() {
    File('mycol.json').create();
  }
}
```

I get the following error when executing:
[image]

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do your app has sufficient permission to create files ? It doesn't seem !

Comment: is that something I need to configure in my app? I'm running in the emulator, haven't change any default configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Unable to create directory (OS Error: Read-only file system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607002/flutter-unable-to-create-directory-os-error-read-only-file-system)

Comment: Also, duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892268/flutter-permission-denied-writing-file

Comment: yes, your app needs sufficient read/write permission to create files on storage.

Comment: using path_provider I don't get the error anymore! I'm guessing I can't see the file in the project because it's inside the device, correct?

Comment: yes, app's private directory. @Icaroto.

Comment: thanks for the links and insight @OMiShah!